# Incorrect Syntax Near Cursor

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-cursor

I have written the below code and it throws an error as 'Incorrect Syntax near mycursor'. Can anyone let me know what am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT DISTINCT [FILE_NAME] INTO #TEMP FROM  [dbo].[ABI_IND_STR_PLAN_DAILY] WHERE Year<>'Year';

DECLARE @var CHAR(20)
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE myCursor CURSOR 
FOR SELECT distinct [FILE_NAME] FROM #TEMP 
--SET @str=''
OPEN myCursor
--'''+@var+''',
FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @var
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
 SET @str=' INSERT INTO [dbo].[ABI_IND_STR_PLAN_DAILY] SELECT 
* from [dbo].[ABI_IND_STR_PLAN_DAILY] WHERE FILE_NAME='+@var ---------------- Change GL Period Accordingly , for eg if it is JUN YTD then GL period '<=6' if only JUN MTD then GL Period = 6

 FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @var
 PRINT(@str)
 EXEC(@str) 
END

CLOSE myCursor
DEALLOCATE myCursor
```

Comment: Runs just fine on my machine (substituting top query with one against `sys.objects` and commenting the `exec` line. Need something *reproducible* if you want answers. (Also, two `distinct`s are unnecessary, but that's not your problem)

Comment: Why do you need a temp table? Why are you intentionally duplicating rows? Why do you think you need dynamic sql? This can all be accomplished in a single statement.  And despite your intentions with "distinct", your logic (as currently written) will select duplicate rows.